# OnRoomCreated returns an error status code, may be due to Google Play Services update

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I want to apologise in advance - my question will be not about programming, but rather about some quirk of Google Play Services we have met.

The situation is the following - we did not update the version or change the settings in developers console, but we got a bit over 10 e-mails from players who cannot play anymore - the game gets something different from `STATUS_OK` in `OnRoomCreated` callback. Nothing is wrong with the code - these players were able to play just a day before, which makes me think about Google Play Services updated in background. The issue was first reported not more that 2 weeks ago.

I know it is not much info, but we did not get the issue on our devices. With only 10+ e-mails from 1000+ daily online players, we are rather unlikely to see it.

Actions already tried without success:

1. Restarting device
2. Reinstalling the game
3. Disconnecting the game from Google Settings\Connected Apps
4. Clearing cache, data and removing updates of Google Play Services
5. Updating to the most recent version of the library

Here we have run out of ideas. If anyone has met the same, or has any good ideas, please, share them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be account-specific, and the only known solution so far is to make a new Google account. My guess is that the players affected were playing the game when something happened (Google Play Services updated?), and now they are still marked as playing that game. So, they can't start a new one. The corresponding issue is here:

https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=70

**Update:** Google team has marked it Fixed.